# Sum of over the sets of reciprocal primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm studying for my number theory exam tomorrow. On our study guide, there are a few questions that I have no idea about.

Firstly, For a set S of prime numbers, explain why the sum 
$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_n} $
converges or may plausibly diverge.

The sets S to consider are:
1) The set of primes of the form 2^m -1
2) The set of primes 1 more than a cube
3) The set of primes with first digit 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first converges, for the series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{2^n-1}$ converges.

The second is a joke question, since $n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)$. So one more than a cube is only prime for $n=1$.

For the third, you may be expected to make only a heuristic argument. Consider the primes from $10^k$ to $10^{k+1}-1$. One expects primes to "thin out" as we travel through this interval, so the total number of primes in this interval should be less than $9$ times the number of primes in the interval from $10^k$ to $2\cdot 10^k-1$.

Thus the sum of the reciprocals of the primes from $10^k$ to $10^{k+1}-1$ should be (well) less than $9$ times the sum of the reciprocals of all the primes from $10^k$ to $2\cdot 10^k-1$.

Add up over all $k$. So one would expect that the sum of the reciprocals of primes that start with the digit $1$ is more than one-ninth the sum of the reciprocals of all primes. But we know that series diverges.

Comment: Beautiful. I'm a little embarrassed at not figuring the first 2 out, I think I was thinking too deeply about them. So I would argue that the third sum would diverge as well. Thank you for your thorough answer.

Comment: Yes, it is converge, converge, diverge. We could also get the convergence of the second from the fact that $\sum \frac{1}{n^3+1}$ converges, but I thought I might as well point out that in this case the sequence of reciprocals is very short. For starting with digit $1$, it is straightforward to give a formal proof of divergence using the Prime Number Theorem. But from the sound of things a heuristic argument is all that is asked for.